# PDF reader that restores last viewed page

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, pdf

Is there a (free) PDF reader that could restore last viewed page when opening a PDF in OS X 10.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preview** can do it. Just be sure that in your Preferences → PDF tab, you have checked the following option:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

And if you have to resave the file (for whatever reasons), use Adobe Reader, which provides the same functionality.

Note: Preview.app can seriously mess up the internal structure of a PDF, so that it is no longer usable.

Comment: Any references or evidence for the last statement?

Comment: Take a fillable smart form, fill it out in Preview.app, and reopen it in Acrobat…